# how to use materialize-css with react and keeping the size of installed components of materialize-css to be minimum

Tags: reactjs, materialize

I am trying to use materialize-css in my React project. How can I set up materialize-css and use it's components with React ?

Comment: Use material-ui

Comment: yes using it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One can use https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize

```
npm install react-materialize
```

Add these to the default html page where you need Material Design.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/materialize.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="path/to/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/your/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Use the components.

```
import { Button, Card, Row, Col } from 'react-materialize';
```

Complete list and how to implement components are listed here: [http://react-materialize.github.io](http://react-materialize.github.io/react-materialize/?path=/story/react-materialize--welcome)

Comment: was more specifically looking for materialize-css and couldn't get to using it without react-materialize, so opted for material-ui in place of react-materialize. Thanks!